# Date format exception is not caught

Tags: java

```
public OrderDate(String date) throws IllegalDateFormatException {   
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
  try {
    dateFormat.parse(date);
    this.date = date;
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new IllegalDateFormatException("Date must have the following format: dd/mm/yy");
  }
}
```

If I use for example 32/05/12 - it doesn't throw an exception.

I also tried:  `Date givenDate = dateFormat.parse(date);`

Need clarification.

Update:

```
public OrderDate(String date) throws IllegalDateFormatException
{   
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
    try 
    {
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        dateFormat.parse(date);
        this.date = date;
    }
    catch(ParseException e) 
    {
        throw new IllegalDateFormatException("Date must have the following"
                                                     + " format: dd/mm/yy");
    }
}
```

It catches the exception, if the date is 32/06/12! At the same time, there is no catch, if the date is 31/06/12. But there are 30 days in June!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `setLenient` of `SimpleDateFormat` is `true`. So, whenever you parse `32/05/12`, it is automatically converted to `01/06/12`. That why no exception is throws. If you need strict parsing than use `setLenient(false)`, it will throw `Exception` at above case. Look at the  [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)).

> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With
>   lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs
>   that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing,
>   inputs must match this object's format.

Comment: you mean dateFormat.setLenient(date) ?

Comment: And catch ParseException as well?

Comment: @ArthurV, Use setLenient(false).

Comment: If setLenient(false), where should be the date argument taken for comparison?

Comment: or you mean use it before dateFormat.parse(date)?

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it! So I don't need a Date object to do .parse(..), do I?

Comment: @ArthurV Look at the parse method in the Javadocs and see what argument(s) it takes. A little experimenting wouldn't hurt either. ;)

Comment: @ArthurV, What is the type of Date. `parse(String)` method except an String.

Comment: I mean, I can do a .parse() comparison in general, without assigning something to something

Comment: @ArthurV, The purpose of  parse method is to convert from date String to Date class. So in your case `this.date=date` does not have any effect of converting. So, you should get the result from parsing like dateClass= format.parse(DateString).

Comment: @Masud  Check the update please. It catches the exception if it is 32/06/12! But it doesn't catch 31/06/12. There are 30 days in June!

Comment: I don't want to convert anything in fact, just need to to assign a String value if it has the correct format. Is that a proper implementation?